# concat 2 column in 1 column with odi 12c in design section

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-data-integrator

I'm new in odi 12c and I want to merge or concat 2 column in 1 column.
I have employee table which has first_name,last_name and ID. I want to map them in another table but full_name and ID.
in sql it is: `employees.first_name||''||employees.last_name as full_name`.
I don't know which component is usefull for doing it(aggregate,set,...?) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of expressions can be added either in an expression component or directly in a target attribute on the target column.

For instance you can just click on the full_name column in the target table and write your expression `employees.first_name||' '||employees.last_name` (NB: I added a space in between).